Unable to perform unattended installation of Oracle Database 19.3.0 on Windows 10
During an unattended installation of Oracle Database 19.3.0 on Windows 10, the following error occurs:
"SEVERE: PRCZ-1082 : Failed to add Windows user or Windows group "REG-XSPY-NUM12$" to Windows group "USERS".
Computer information:
Window 10 
Admin User: winki 
Computer name: REG-XSPY-NUM12 
Workgroup: DSTORES 
IsBuiltInAccount = true 

Log file:

WindowsSecurityException has occurred SEVERE: PRCZ-1082 : Failed to add Windows user or Windows group "REG-XSPY-NUM12$" to Windows group "USERS" WSE-000031: Unable to add user to operating system group.


INFO: Exception thrown from action: AddInstallUserToGroup enter code here Exception Name: WindowsSecurityException has occurred Exception String: Failed to add DSTORES\REG-XSPY-NUM12$ install user to %2% group

User 'REG-XSPY-NUM12$' does not exist on my machine. I’m curious why the computer account username 'REG-XSPY-NUM12$' was selected to add to the Users group.
Is there a way for us to use the username 'winki' instead of the machine name during the Oracle installation?
I hope to receive a response from you, thank you very much.

Can you provide response file, IMHO this user is there

the user 'REG-XSPY-NUM12$' does not exist on my machine at all That is the computer name. It probably means it is running as system, instead of user account credentials. Or don't use "AddInstallUserToGroup".

Thank you for your response. This is my RSP file  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oE6yrlpo76GAgC_oaUAKWrS9ujeYsh-1/view?usp=sharing. I have checked, and there is only one user 'winki' on that machine, and I ran it with admin privileges. There is no Antivirus, no firewall, and no domain on that machine.

Greg, I tried installing it on some other machines, and the installation was successful. From the logs, I noticed that Oracle is using the username (not the machine name) to add to the User group. I don't understand why there is such a difference. Can you let me know what the next step should be? Thanks a lot.

Try renaming the computer to a shorter name if possible.
